# Check for empty rows in a table view on selecting Continue button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, mvvm

I have a code written using MVVM architecture and I am trying to check if the tableView cells are empty on selecting the Continue button. The View controller file is as below

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        continueButton?.isEnabled = true
        continueButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(continueClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func continueClicked() {
     viewModel.checkFieldsForError()
    }
.
.
.
   override func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Some code
    }
```

The ViewModelfile is as below

```
 func checkFieldsForError(){

     }
```

Could someone point me on how to approach this problem. I am at loss on how to access the table fields in the continue clicked function. Please let me know if the information provided is insufficient.

Comment: Don't check the contents of the tableView, but check your model instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create some handlers and use them to present that data back to View.. Example

```
func checkFieldsForError(someFailure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        let hasError = true
        if hasError {
            let error = Error()
            someFailure(error)
        } else {
            someFailure(nil)
        }
    }
```

call the method as follows

```
  viewModel.checkFieldsForError { (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = errror {
                // Some error occurred

            } else {
                // no error occurred
            }
        }
```